# How to assign parent reference to child's object using spring get bean

Tags: java, spring

```
@Component
public abstract class Person 
{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int age;

    //getter and setter methods

}

@Component
public class Customer extends Person
{
    private String custId;
       //getter and setter methods
}



public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context = 
          new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"Spring-Customer.xml"});

        Person person= context.getBean(Customer.class);


    }
```

Here I want to use the Person class reference to call the Customer class object. But it is giving me compilation error. Please let me know how to assign abstract class reference to child class object using get bean

Comment: it will ask type case for any bean, just add explicit type casting

Comment: What compilation error do you have? What is the message? Are you sure this is a compilation error?